# Cookies handling when client-side is also an ExpressJS app

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, session-cookies

As far as I'm concerned, for a server side application to know what clients are communicating with it, it will save a cookie in the client with the session ID.

That is indeed what `express-session` a popular package for session storage in ExpressJS says in the documentation

> Note Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.

So I believe I can assume this is strategy used by Express to maintain user data in sessions as well.

I did something else: I'm using Redis to store the Session data in my ExpressJS server app.

So having said that, my problem is that my client application is also an Express app. I have a nodejs app with Express both for client and server. There is a SPA involved in this problem, but it communicates with the 'express client' so it appears to be a different problem.

So everytime I send a request from Express Client to Express Server, there is not cookie being passed, so it can't identify a session ID and creates a new one, generating lots of garbage in Redis and making the session solution useless.

How should I save or fake a cookie in the Express Client app, or, even better, how this kind of problem is solved?

Actually if I knew what the Express Server is expecting in the request (a cookie, a header or whatever) I think I can solve the problem.

Anyone know what to do?

**@Solved**

Alright, so, in my nodejs client application I did the following:

```
login(req,res,next){
    var options = {
      url : 'http://localhost:8090/user/login_handler';
    };

    request(options, function(error,response,body) {
      var cookie_string = response['headers']['set-cookie'][0].split(';')[0];
      req.session.cookie_string = cookie_string;
    });
}

check(req,res,next){
    var options = {
      url : 'http://localhost:8090/user/check_handler',
      headers: {
        'cookie':req.session.cookie_string
      }
    };

    request(options, function(error,response,body){
      res.json( body);
    });
}
```

In short, when the session is created in the server side, it will respond with headers to tell the client to create a cookie. I save the important information to pass as a cookie in a different moment. The server-side then read the headers in the middleware and load the correect data to the session.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  If you aren't sending cookies to the "Express Server" app, why is the `express-session` module being used?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your architecture I would guess that what you want is to either set the [`saveUnitialized`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized) option to `false`, and not save the extraneous sessions, or only apply the `express-session` middleware to certain routes in your "Express Server" application

Comment: I want to make the sessions available in the server, that is a ExpressJS webserver, of a client that is also a NodeJS/ExpressJS.

Browser - Node, node would say "browser, save a cookie and everytime you call me, send me your cookies", but now there is no browser. It's Node Client - Node Server.

Comment: Did you write the "Node Client", or is it a library like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)?  It seems like you just need to send the right cookie to the "Node Server" app.

Comment: I mean a node application. I'm using Request, yes.
And I found a way, exactly was you said.